# Reset input value to initial value on condition in React Final Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

How is it possible to reset `values.range` to `initialValues.range` after `condition` is set to `true` in https://codesandbox.io/s/xjxx7xp07q  ?

May you tell where I am missing the point? Many thanks for all possible help.

**UPDATE**

Found working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/l706w7yr2q , but have no idea how to refactor component into Wizard form case xD 
any help appreciated, from where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution using [Declarative Form Rules](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#declarative-form-rules)

Working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/zwr2o7xo0m